# Looking for Windows-based software for opening a WireShark .dump file w/o WireShark

Tags: windows-xp, file-format, file-converter

Apparently there is a way in Ubuntu, but I'm on a Windows box.  XP, to be specific.  I want to import this data into Access, but can't figure out how to even open the file and Access won't recognize the extension.

Does anyone know how to open one of these files, or convert it to something Access understands?

Here's the Ubuntu link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594860/how-do-i-open-a-dump-file-format-in-ubuntu-without-using-wireshark

Comment: Maybe this leads you somewhere https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/200804/msg00270.html. BTW I got that [through Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=wireshark+dump+file)

Comment: Was there information on how to open a .dump file from Windows at that link?  Because I didn't see any.

Comment: Johnny, the extension `.dump` can stand for many things – it's neither bound to an application nor to a media type. Can you please [edit] your question and include what kind of file that is (what was it created by, and what it's supposed to contain)? // Just seeing your answer: Yes, MySQL is one example. It could well have been some binary dump from some other app :)

Comment: If a .dump file is not specific to WireShark, then the guy who edited my question should roll it back.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Wireshark dump files are [pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) files.

A couple of options:

- Open them using [tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/) which produces text output, which you could parse in Access code.
- Read them using a library such as [pcap.net](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net), which I think you can use from Access.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html) which will read a pcap file and will even write them, (it will also allow you to capture traffic without wireshark and generate traffic which wireshark will not do).

Example of reading from the [demo](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html):

```
>>> a=rdpcap("/spare/captures/isakmp.cap")
>>> a
<isakmp.cap: UDP:721 TCP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>
>>> a[423].pdfdump(layer_shift=1)
>>> a[423].psdump("/tmp/isakmp_pkt.eps",layer_shift=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[VEdit](https://www.vedit.com/) will open files with a .dump extension.  Turns out the files in question are simple ASCII and look like MySQL code to recreate tables of data, complete with table layouts and insert statements.  I'll have to see whether or not I can import them into MySQL or if they need to be converted first.